# Plot the domain when using "quiver"

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm using on Matlab the function `quiver` in order to plot a velocity vector field. The problem is that when I call

```
quiver(Xvel,Yvel,Ux,Uy)
```

I get only the arrows without showing the grid of the domain. Is it possible to show also the domain where this field lives?

I tried `hold on` with the function `surf` but it covers all the plot of `quiver`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick here is to plot the surf in a lower Z , so the quiver arrows are in the top of the surf plot.

Here is a simple example (witha couple of "fancy plotting" tricks):

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-2:.2:2);
Z = X.*exp(-X.^2 - Y.^2);
[DX,DY] = gradient(Z,.2,.2);

figure
surf(X,Y,Z-max(Z(:)),'linestyle','none','facecolor','interp');
colormap gray
hold on
quiver(X,Y,DX,DY,'r','linewidth',1)
hold off
view(2)
axis([-2 2 -2 2])
```

[image]